# indexOf in Java - ArrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication10Arraylistandobjects {

    static Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    public static void test(){
        ArrayList<mainclass> me = new ArrayList <> ();
        mainclass ob;
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            ob = new mainclass();
            System.out.println("name");
            ob.name = user_input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("sname");
            ob.sname = user_input.nextLine();
            me.add(ob);
        }
        System.out.println("Show List: " + me);
        System.out.println("Confirm if is true or false: " + me.get(1).toString().contains("max"));
        System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.get(1).toString().indexOf("max"));
    }
}
```

```
public class mainclass {

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "mainclass{" + "name=" + name + ", sname=" + sname + '}';
    }

    String name;
    String sname;
}
```

My questions is how can I find correctly indexOf string.
For example when I am checking if string "max" exist - it shows me "true"
 and when I am trying to find index of string "max" it shows me index  15 which is not correct.

P.S. I found an article with the same problem where it says that I have to override equals and hashcode - I've done it but anyway I got the same problem.

Please point me to the right direction.
What I am doing wrong here, can someone explain me pls.

These are my inputs and output.

- run: 
  name Jony 
  sname Bravo

name max 
sname hitman

Show List:[mainclass{name=Jony, sname=Bravo}, mainclass{name=max, sname=hitman}]

Confirm if is true or false: true 
what is index of: 15

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

Comment: Why do you think 15 is not correct?

Comment: And what would you expect the correct value to be?

Comment: I am expecting to see index 1.

Comment: But the string starts with `"mainclass{" + "name="`

Comment: The string `"max"` is at index 15 in the string `"mainclass{name=max, sname=hitman}"` so 15 is correct.

Comment: On index 0 - Jony - Bravo and on index 1 max hitman, I am expecting to see on index 1

Comment: As I understand I don't need index from mainclass but I need index from my ArrayList

Comment: Do you really want to search for the index of the string `max` in string representation of your `mainclass` instance?

Comment: `me` is an `ArrayList`.  `me.get(1)` is a `MainClass`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing two indexOf methods (methods of String and List).

Comment: I think you are confusing `String.indexOf` with `List.indexOf`. In your code you are calling String.indexOf which returns the correct position of the substring max in your input.

Comment: then if I understood correctly I need to change :         System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.get(1).toString().indexOf("max"));
 to a new one which looks : System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.indexOf("max")); is it correct ?

Comment: It's not correct, but it's getting closer.  I think we can at least see what the issue is and what you want to be doing, now, and can write an answer.

Comment: I just change that line to a new one : System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.indexOf("max")); , and now I am getting the result -1 - which means does not exist as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
    System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.get(1).toString().indexOf("max"));
```

has a problem, in that you're getting the object in the `me` list at index 1, getting its `toString()`, and looking for "max" in there.  What you actually want to do, as I understand it, is look through the `me` list and find the place in the list with "max" in it.

> P.S. I found an article with the same problem where it says that I have to override equals and hashcode - I've done it but anyway I got the same problem.

If you did that, it would allow you to do something like this:

```
x = new mainclass();
x.setName("Max");
System.out.println("what is index of: " + me.indexOf(x));
```

However, there's still a potential problem.  Unless you set your `equals()` and `hashCode()` to only look at the `name` and not also `sname`, then it's not going to find anything unless the `sname` *also* matches.